# Thumb drives over networks

Tags: usb-flash-drive

If I insert a thumb drive on a network computer with 5 files on it and I open one file, and then remove it, would the other 4 files be accessible to anyone at a later time?

Comment: No... Do you have some reason to think anyone can access files on a drive that is no longer connected to a workstation?

Comment: I guess I thought the network might make a copy of every file it encountered, even if the file was never opened.

Comment: This would be a extremely unusually situation if it did, especially for a removeable drive. I am assuming this is in a corporate environment, so if you are concerned about this possibility I would contact your internal IT support for more information. Although, testing this would be simple... access the file you want, remove the drive, can you still access the files? I would imagine not...

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible.

The host machine machine could have a script or program that copies or backs up the USB drive on insertion.

Once a machine has access to your drive, it can do *anything* with that data.  Simply put, do not give a machine access your drive/data that you do not trust, as you do not know what it might do with it.